# Setting up JuJu Local instance on UbuntuVM with Joomla, can't connect?

Tags: networking, juju, joomla

I setup a Ubuntu vm 14.04 in hyper-v, included a virtual switch, opened up port 80 on the router for that specific address, and I still cannot connect to the joomla charm. I can ping the vm just fine from the the public ip, but when in a web browser I get Connection Refused. I opened port 80 on the linux vm as well. I need help configuring this.